# Page loading before transition effects happen

Tags: css-transitions, zurb-foundation, transition, pjax

I finally got PJAX all setup and working perfect on my Foundation 5 site and its time to add my page transitions. For some reason no matter what I try the page loads and then the transition happens.

[Here is my website with with one of the transitions I tried](http://backtobasicsbirthservices.com/test)

I've also tried simple things like:

```
$(document)
  .on('pjax:start', function() { $('#main').fadeOut(200); })
  .on('pjax:end',   function() { $('#main').fadeIn(200); })
```

I also ran into aenism.com/teleportation-is-scary/ in my searches for a solution and its what I currently have running on my pages.

Here is an example of it working: [Demo Site](http://playground.meekostuff.net/jquery-pjax/demo/aliens.html)

I'm not sure what the problem could be at this point.

Comment: Do you have a demo of the non-working code at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works perfect for fading out and back in again.  I have not tested it with other animations but it looks like it should do the trick.  I hope this helps someone else!

```
       // USER CLICKS LINK WITH PJAX CLASS
  $('body').delegate('a.pjax', 'click', function() {
    // CONTENT FADE OUT TRANSITION BEGINS
    $('#main-content').fadeOut(300, function() {
        // CALLBACK TO RUN PJAX AFTER FADEOUT
        $.pjax({
          url: target,
          container: '#main-content',
          fragment: '#main-content'
        })
    })
     // STOP THE LINK FROM WORKING NORMALLY
    return false;
  })

  // PJAX DOIN THANGS TO THE CONTENT FRAGMENT IDENTIFIED ABOVE
  $('#main-content')
    .on('pjax:start', function() { 
      // KEEPING THE MAIN CONTENT HIDDEN
      $(this).fadeOut(0)
    })
    .on('pjax:end',   function() { 
      // FADE IN THE MAIN CONTENT
      $(this).fadeIn(300)
      // FUNCTIONS LOADED AGAIN AFTER PJAX ENDS GO HERE
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

WOOO That suggestion worked, had to tweak it a bunch to get it to fit with my page transitions, but this is what I ended up with (works off of css3 animations):

```
$("body").delegate('a[data-pjax]', 'click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    if (contentpage == "true" || errorpage == "true") { $(".contentimage").append('<div class="pjax-loading"></div>'); }
    $("body").removeClass("pjax-fadeIn").addClass("pjax-fadeOut").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $.pjax({url: target, container: '#content', fragment: '#content'});
    });
    return false;
})

$("#content").on('pjax:start', function() {
    $("body").removeClass("pjax-fadeOut").addClass("pjax-hide");
}).on('pjax:complete', function() {
    $("body").removeClass("pjax-hide").addClass("pjax-fadeIn");
});
```